# (Urban airship) How can I remove(or update) previous push message alert?

Tags: android, cordova, push

My app service is android app using `phonegap` and push alarm service is one of the app services.

Current our push alarm service is continuously adding a message on upside-status-bar as push notification alarm.

See this >> http://www.givetime.co.kr/qna.png

But i want to replace the message newest one not add, i.e. i want to display only one message on the bar.

How can i replace or How can i display only one message?

this is my push alarm service code.

send alarm code to "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/ " as post a json message :

```
{
"apids": [
"user APID",
],
"android": {
"alert": "You received a message."
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, urban airship display all the messages that receives in the status bar, but you can change this behavior but setting your own notification builder and setting the variable **constantNotificationId** to a integer bigger than 0 in order to replace previous notifications.

Here is an example of how to configure a CustomPushNotificationBuilder in the Android application class:

```
 CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();

   nb.layout = R.layout.notification_layout; // The layout resource to use
   nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.notification_icon; // The icon you want to display
   nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon; // The icon's layout 'id'
   nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject; // The id for the 'subject' field
   nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message; // The id for the 'message' field

   //set this ID to a value > 0 if you want a new notification to replace the previous one
   nb.constantNotificationId = 100;

   //set this if you want a custom sound to play
   nb.soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/" +R.raw.notification_mp3);

   // Set the builder
   PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
```

You can check more information in the [Urban Airship documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/android-lib/reference/com/urbanairship/push/CustomPushNotificationBuilder.html)

Comment: One more thing I wonder.. How can remove recevied alert when I app start?

Comment: You can use in your Activity the [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll%28%29 "NotificationManager Android documentation") and the function `cancelAll()` to cancel all previously shown notifications.

Comment: is there any way to set default text in the case of multiple notification?

Comment: You can override the function `buildNotification` in the `CustomPushNotificationBuilder` and return the string you want to use in case of multiple notification.
You can read more in the [official documentation](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android_features.html), under the section **BasicPushNotificationBuilder**.